# How can I make four sprites looped so it behaves like a GIF act as ONE sprite?

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

So I have four sprites that I have edited in paint so when looping through them it looks like a GIF. How can I make these 4 sprites that constantly loops so they look like a GIF behave like ONE sprite?

How can I make all the four sprites go left and right as one sprite when pressing left and right?

Here is the code for the "GIF":

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import sys

pygame.init()


class Flame(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, images, time_interval):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_1 = pygame.image.load('images/a.bmp')
        self.image_2 = pygame.image.load('images/b.bmp')
        self.image_3 = pygame.image.load('images/c.bmp')
        self.image_4 = pygame.image.load('images/d.bmp')

        self.images = [self.image_1, self.image_2, self.image_3, self.image_4]
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.time_interval = time_interval
        self.index = 0
        self.timer = 0

    def update(self, seconds):
        self.timer += seconds
        if self.timer >= self.time_interval:
            self.image = self.images[self.index]
            self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.images)
            self.timer = 0


def create_images():
    images = []
    for i in range(4):
        image = pygame.Surface((256, 256))
        images.append(image)
    return images


def main():
    images = create_images()
    a = Flame(images, 0.25)

    # Main loop.
    while True:
        seconds = clock.tick(FPS) / 500.0

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        a.update(seconds)
        screen.fill((230, 230, 230))
        screen.blit(a.image, (250, 100))
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    main()
```

How can I make these sprites that loops go left when pressing left and right when pressing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the position where you blit `a.image`.

You hard coded `(250, 100)` and use `screen.blit` to draw the sprite on the screen, but usually, when using pygame, you should use a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead.

A `Sprite`  should have a `rect` attribute that contains its size and position. So to actually change the position of a `Sprite` when a key is pressed, you need to change the x/y-attributes of that `Rect`.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import sys

pygame.init()


class Flame(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, time_interval):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_1 = pygame.image.load('images/a.bmp')
        self.image_2 = pygame.image.load('images/b.bmp')
        self.image_3 = pygame.image.load('images/c.bmp')
        self.image_4 = pygame.image.load('images/d.bmp')

        self.images = [self.image_1, self.image_2, self.image_3, self.image_4]
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.time_interval = time_interval
        self.index = 0
        self.timer = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(250, 100))

    def update(self, seconds):
        self.timer += seconds
        if self.timer >= self.time_interval:
            self.image = self.images[self.index]
            self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.images)
            self.timer = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.rect.move_ip((-1, 0))
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.rect.move_ip((1, 0))

def main():
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Flame(0.25))
    # Main loop.
    while True:
        seconds = clock.tick(FPS) / 500.0

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        sprites.update(seconds)
        screen.fill((230, 230, 230))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I craeted this function to aid my pygame animation

```
def animate(animation_tick, animation_speed, animation_counter, animations, pause=False):

# increment the tick so animations happen at certain points - this the same as the game tick
animation_tick += 1
# change the image to the next in the list
if animation_tick % animation_speed == 0:
    if not pause:
        animation_counter += 1
    # animation list has finished, reset it so it starts again.

    if animation_counter > len(animations) - 1:
        animation_counter = 0
        animation_tick = 0
return animation_counter, animation_tick, animations[animation_counter]
```

then call that function with in my enemy class

```
def animate(self, animations, flip = None):
    """
    :param animations:
    :param animation_state:
    :return:
    """

    self.moving_animation_counter, self.animation_tick, image = \
        animate(self.animation_tick, self.animation_speed, self.moving_animation_counter, animations)
    if flip:
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
    return pygame.transform.scale(image, (self.rect.width, self.rect.height))
```